Adding input field on click of a button in Angular
I am new to Angular and I am trying to build a UI with a form where one field is constant and 5 other fields should be displayed (appended) to the existing form with a click of a button and the user can add only 4 times at max and should be saved in the DB we are using .Net core for that. I tried to use the examples from the internet but it is not working.
Need help

have you tried anything? If yes, then please share whatever you have tried

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78971644/need-help-in-adding-dynamic-ui-elements-in-angular Pasted here
